# how to get rowid when insert a row to table

Tags: cocoa, sqlite

I hope to add a row to a table in a sqlite database.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO myTable (rowid,myName ) VALUES (NULL, '%@');" , [aInfo myString]];
```

rowid is auto increment.

After insert the row, I hope to get the rowid that generate by sqlite automatically.

Is it possible?

welcome any comment

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the new generated id with the **last_insert_rowid() function**. See http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html

You do not say what language are you using, but search in your SQLite library implementation for last_insert_rowid function...

Comment: caligari: The code snippet in the question is in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
select max(rowid) from myTable